# Tkinter Browse Button Self Deleting

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a browse button in tkinter. I have created the open folder dialog box but when i set it to the button it will exit out of the window.

My ultimate goal is to:
1) click on the button and bring up the file dialogue box
2) select a file
3) insert the file name into an Entry Widget for later use

I should note that I am using multiple window frames for the code that follows is summed up.

```
import os
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def openFile(entryWidgetName):
    tk.Tk().withdraw() 
    filename = askopenfilename()
    entryWidgetName.delete(0,tk.END)
    entryWidgetName.insert(0,filename)
    return

class Welcome():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.buttonNewTemplate = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Create a New Template', command = self.gotoNewTemplate).place(x=100, y=250)
    def gotoNewTemplate(self):
        root2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        newTemplate = NewTemplate(root2)


class NewTemplate():
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Entry Windows
        self.uploadFile = tk.Entry(self.sectionFrame2, width = 80).grid(row=4, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        #Buttons
        self.buttonBrowse=tk.Button(self.sectionFrame2, text='Browse', fg='blue', command=lambda:openFile(uploadFile)).grid(row=4, column = 0, padx = 10, sticky = 'w')
```

Every time I click the browse button the second window destroys itself bringing me back to the main page.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A tkinter application can only have a single instance of `Tk`. You are creating at least two: one explicitly in `openFile`, and one from somewhere else in your code either implicitly or explicitly.

Since the only way to call `openFile` is from a button click, and the only way to have a button click is to have a button, and the only way to have a button is to already have a root window, you need to remove the statement `tk.Tk().withdraw()` since that is creating a new root window.

There may be other problems in your code, but it's impossible to know based on the incomplete code in the question.